# Solr 'service unaveliable'

Tags: apache, solr

So, i've been following 'djnaog by example' and one of the assignments is to integrate django and solr with haystack. I tried to follow the readme included in solr package, but idk why, it doestn seem to work when i visit localhost 8983. At http://127.0.0.1:9999/solr/ i get message 'Service Unavailable', in terminal i get :

> "*** [WARN]**  Your open file limit is currently 1024.    It should
>   be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.   If you no longer
>   wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your
>   profile or solr.in.sh
>    **[WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 62864.   It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.   If you no
>   longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in
>   your profile or solr.in.sh Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr
>   running on port 9999 [|]   Started Solr server on port 9999
>   (pid=11255). Happy searching!"

I have no idea what to do so please help

Let me add that i used

> ./bin/solr start

in bash

**Update**:

**Tried:**

> ./solr status commnad

**Output:**

> "Found 4 Solr nodes:   Solr process 11255 from
>   /home/pawe/Pulpit/solr-8.1.1/solr/bin/solr-9999.pid not found.
>
> Solr process 10702 from
>   /home/pawe/Pulpit/solr-8.1.1/solr/bin/solr-8888.pid not found.
>
> Solr process 3174 running on port 8983
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI Solr process 11124 from
>   /home/pawe/Pulpit/solr-8.1.1/solr/bin/solr-8866.pid not found. "

Comment: `Started Solr server on port **9999** (pid=11255). Happy searching!`. If you expected Solr to be on the default port of 8983, that's your issue.

Comment: @MatsLindh, sorry I tried to use different ports hoping it would help (it didn't) and i pasted one of my 'experimental' links by mistake

Comment: What does your Solr log say when starting up? You can avoid Solr being put in the background by giving the `-f` parameter when starting it